# Android: Tracking opening/closing of word,pdf,excel etc files in my app

Tags: android

In my app, I want to track opening & closing of word/pdf/excel files. Please suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, you cannot "track opening & closing of word/pdf/excel files" from an ordinary SDK application, as this would be a privacy violation.